# Get file last saved time qt

Tags: qt

I'm trying to get the last modified time of a text file I am saving in a notepad app I built.

I can get the file directory using this code:

```
QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a file");
ui->filePathLabel->setText(file);
```

How can I extract a last saved time from this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [QFileInfo::lastModified()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qfileinfo.html#lastModified):

```
const QFileInfo info(file);
const QDateTime lastModified = info.lastModified();
...
```

Comment: Ideal, what would be the best way to convert the QDateTime to QString?

Comment: `lastModified.toString( Qt::ISODate );` or without parameters to receive simple string.

Comment: The string ends up saying "2014-01-17T10:59:08". How can I configure this so I have it in this format...HH:MM followed by am/pm and then DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: @Luke this is pretty much standard time. You can always define your own format - it's all in documentation http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#toString e.g. "h:mm ap yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: There are also various options to get localized dates (use as argument to toString()): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#DateFormat-enum